# How to play a video when closing android application

Tags: android

friends, I am developing an android application. I want to play a thanks video when I exit my application. can anyone suggest any method, please..?

Comment: you want to play thanks video **where** ? If you're planning to close your app

Comment: yes. if i exit the application, the application closes with playing a thanks video.

Comment: so  application will be closed **after** playing a video

Comment: yes. if I am trying to close an application the thanks video will play and application closed after playing the video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Use onBackPressed(); or When U Close The App

Hear Simple Example..... You Can Modify as Your Use

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1); your VideoView Default Visiblity is GONE

    vv.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE);
    uri = "your video uri";
    vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri));
    vv.start();

    vv.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
           //Video Finish 
            super.onBackPressed();
  }
});


}
```

> OR

```
public void closinApplicationShowVideo()
{
        videoView.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE);
        uri = "your video uri";
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri));
        videoView.start();

        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
               //Video Finish 
                //Apply Your Logic To Close Application
      }
    });

}
```

> Note :  If You Have One Or More Activity Then U need To create One New
>   Activity for this Video in This Activity Write Code To Playvideo on
>   Complition close The Application....
>
> Call VideoView Activity onBackPressed in Other Activity

Like

in Your Other Activity when User Try To Close Application like backpress

Call Activity on BackPressed

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        //Note Dont Call super.onBackPressed();
       startActivity(new Intent(currentActivity.this,videoViewActivity.class));
finish();
}
```

Comment: where i place the video view? in my MainActivity means the first screen of my application?

Comment: if you have one or more activity the u need to create activity for this videoView

Comment: sorry Ashvin. i can't understand what you say. can you explain please.

Comment: @RosemaryRajan any time sir